# How to sum a third field in a MySQL count/groub by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I need to group data by.  For instance I need a count of how many rows are entered for one user.  So I can do a simple count/group by

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as total FROM `ad` group by user_id
```

But there's another field "price" that I need a total of from added rows. The price of the ad is not static, so I cant just do $75 X number of rows,  I need a function that adds each price field and give me a total for all the rows of a given user

I've tried some union statements like:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as total FROM `ad` group by user_id union All select sum(price) from ad
```

Obviously above wont work but just showing what I'm thinking

Here is the table, maybe this will help understanding.  So essential I need a total count of how many ad's were placed by particular users, but I also need the price of each ad sumed as I need this information for showing revenue purposes

```
CREATE TABLE `ad` (
 `ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ad_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `path_location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `isActive` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`),
 KEY `fk_ad_type_ad` (`ad_type_id`),
 KEY `fk_user_id_ad` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_ad_type_ad` FOREIGN KEY (`ad_type_id`) REFERENCES `ad_type` (`ad_type_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id_ad` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Expected results will be such as:

User 34 has posted 22 ads which generated a revenue of $560 dollars.  I need three data points but group by only allows two?

Comment: What does `SUM(price)` even give you???  It doesn't make sense, and obviously wrong.

Comment: yes as you see in my description of that query I say "obviously this is wrong but showing how I'm thinking"  I need that third data point.

Comment: why can't you just include a sum(price) column after your count...?

Comment: Oh, weird.  I had thought I tried that before and it said now but I think because I was just adding price, not sum price.  Works now.  I feel dumb.  If you want to make an answer chirs I'll give it to you

Comment: Not sure why but I though groub by only allowed one selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot you can simply add a `sum()` to the query?

```
SELECT user_id,
       count(*) total,
       sum(price) price
       FROM ad
       GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Yes.  I thought I had tried this but I guess not!  Thanks.